# Validação de Campos Java Web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou fazendo uma validação de campos no meu projeto, entretanto programei para que o erro de campo vazio aparecesse somente no campo "nome" pois ainda estou elaborando. Porém a mensagem de erro está aparecendo em todos os campos, tanto para a validação bem sucedida quanto para a mensagem de erro.

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction1() { 

   var valor = document.getElementById("nome").value;
   if (valor == null || valor.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(valor)) {
     $("#nome").parent().parent().attr("class", "form-group2 has-error");
     $("#nome").parent().children("span").text("O campo deve ser preenchido").show();
     return false;
   }

   else {
     $("#nome").parent().parent().attr("class", "form-group2 has-success");
     $("#nome").parent().children("span").text("").hide(); 
     alert("Informações gravadas com sucesso");

   }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Cadastro de Indivíduo</h2>
  <form role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="id">ID:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled="" id="usr">
    </div>

    <form action="" role="form">

      <div class="form-group2">

        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome">
        <span class="help-block"></span>

      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rg">RG:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id=rg>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="npai">Nome do pai:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="npai">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nmae">Nome da mãe:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nmae">
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nascimento">Data de nascimento:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="nascimento">
      </div>


    </form>

    <button type="button" id="gravar" class=" btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction1()">Gravar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Limpar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction2()">Excluir</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Onde estão os "todos os campos" que estão fazendo a validação?

Comment: @ Weslley Tavares não os coloquei aqui pois não foram refenciados no js..

Comment: Justamente, se não foram referenciados no JS, como estão sendo impactados pela validação que ocorre somente para um determinado elemento? Seria uma boa você incluir a sua página toda para que alguém possa (com maior facilidade) te ajudar a encontrar a solução.